# Using Dic to find match and updating columns in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I'm trying to accomplish the below task using `Dictionary` : (don't ask why :P, I just found this method and started using it and didn't look out for other possibilities, any better method is welcomed)

- Check Col AE in sheet "DRG" for the string "TRUE".
- If that is found, then compare values in Col E of sheet "DRG" with Col R of sheet "Latency".
- If a match is found in Sheet "Latency" and if it has the value "TRUE" in sheet DRG, then update the text "IP" in Col S in "Latency" sheet.

I have the below code and not sure where to include the line that compares Col R of Sheet "Latency" and Col E of sheet "DRG"

**My Code**

```
Sub IPFinder()

Dim cl As Range, Dic As Object

Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary"): Dic.Comparemode = vbTextCompare

With Sheets("Latency")
    For Each cl In .Range("R2:R" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
        If Not Dic.exists(cl.Value) Then Dic.Add cl.Value, cl.Row
    Next cl
End With

With Sheets("DRG")
    For Each cl In .Range("AE2:AE" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        If Dic.exists(cl.Value) = "TRUE" Then
            Sheets("Latency").Cells(Dic(cl.Value), 19) = "IP"
        End If
        If Dic.exists(cl.Value) Then
            Sheets("Latency").Cells(Dic(cl.Value), 19) = "IP"
            Dic.Remove (cl.Value)
        End If
    Next cl
End With
Set Dic = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: your narrative doesn't match your code:  I took the former as the valid one and posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following your description:

> - Check Col AE in sheet "DRG" for the string "TRUE".
> - If that is found,then compare values in Col E of sheet "DRG" with Col R of sheet "Latency".
> - If a match is found in Sheet "Latency" and if it has the
>     value "TRUE" in sheet DRG, then update the text "IP" in Col S in
>     "Latency" sheet.

the code should be adjusted as follows (see comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub IPFinder()
    Dim cl As Range, Dic As Object

    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary"): Dic.Comparemode = vbTextCompare

    With Sheets("Latency")
        For Each cl In .Range("R2:R" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
            If Not Dic.exists(cl.Value) Then Dic.Add cl.Value, cl.Row
        Next cl
    End With

    With Sheets("DRG")
        With .Range("AE1:AE" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row) '<--| reference its column AE range from row 1 (header) down to the one corresponding to last column A not empty row
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="TRUE" '<--| filter column AE cells with "TRUE" content
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell found
                For Each cl In .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1, -26).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<--| loop through column "E" cells correesponding to filtered ones in column "AE" (skipping headers)
                    If Dic.exists(cl.Value) Then Sheets("Latency").Cells(Dic(cl.Value), "S") = "IP" '<--| if cirrent column E cell value matches any "Latency" sheet column R one then write "IP" in "Latency" sheet corresponding column S cell
                Next
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    Set Dic = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Just what I needed!! Thanks

Comment: congrats on reaching 20K !

Comment: @user3598756 LOL, no, you and I jave been answering on the 50% of the same posts here, so I can see your points (too frequently :)